CORS policy error in react js , tried to call NASA API but getting cors error
I am trying to fetch data from NASA's techport API, but I am getting errors related to cors.


async function fetchData() {
  try {
    console.log("call");
    let response = await fetch(
      "https://techport.nasa.gov/api/projects?updatedSince=2024-05-01&api_key=cRtIbE8a71e3DocpmbtFi6587DrwszRSfBWogrbp"
    );

    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
fetchData();



I am getting this error:
(error_image)
Access to fetch at 'https://techport.nasa.gov/api/projects?updatedSince=2024-05-01&api_key=cRtIbE8a71e3DocpmbtFi6587DrwszRSfBWogrbp' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have searching for different solution regarding cors I tried proxy,
but that didn't work, but I was able to call a local server which calls NASA API, it worked,
but I want to do it without creating a server.

This is a security feature of browsers that you can't circumvent

@Evert Isn't there any way to resolve this?

Why would I lie?

but I want to do it without creating a server. then use (may not be free of course) someone elses server that allows you to proxy requests through it ... when you say I tried proxy - what did you actually do?
